# Resource recomendation - very specific topic?

Tags: discussion

Let us say that I want source of information that gives worked examples for a very specific topic (let us call it X). I have access to a (pretty good) library and have searched both this and the world wide web endlessly for some examples - to no avail. Clearly what I am after can not be found by a quick google search. Would it be appropriate to ask for such a resource on PSE or would it likely get closed of been off topic. (I suspect the latter hence why I am checking here first).

Comment: Have you looked up [our specific-reference](http://physics.stackexchange.com/tags/specific-reference/info) tag and related discussions here on Meta?

Comment: [Ask in chat first](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71/the-h-bar). That's always a risk free option. It tends to be busiest in the afternoon/evenings (in GMT), presumably when we Europeans have finished work and the US is just getting going.

Comment: @tpg2114 I have looked at related discussions but I didn't know that tag existed, thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: There is also the tag [tag:resource-recommendations], which has [very specific guidelines](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/4697) for its use. It sounds like your question is on-topic, but of course that depends on the details and you do need to read the guidelines. That link also explains the difference between the two tags.

Comment: @tpg2114 This would almost certainly _not_ be appropriate for [tag:specific-reference]. (Though I can't complain about making more people aware of it.)

Comment: @DavidZ Really? A direct quote from the tag wiki: "This is also for requests for where to find a resource when it has been demonstrated that that PDF has been hard to find." Did I misunderstand the question or the tag wiki?

Comment: @tpg2114 That part comes from the excerpt, which is the non-authoritative summary. But anyway, yes, you did misunderstand - though I can see why, it's not very clearly explained. That sentence refers to questions where you have the _exact bibliographical details_ of the reference (or at least, enough to uniquely identify it), but you just can't find the actual _content_ of the paper. I'll edit to make that clearer.

Comment: ([This](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/27503/reference-request-susskind-glogower-original-paper) is an example in action of that aspect of the tag, with the linked meta discussion providing more details.)